# realloc printing old contents

Tags: pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, c99, realloc

realloc still prints old content even reallocated size is decreased.
until i add null byte to the end  of the string.
-fsanitize=address gives error ==7126==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address.
if realloc free remaining block then why overflow occurs for the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUL '\0'

void check_allocation_success(char *ptr);

int main(void) {
   char *str1, *str2;
   str1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*17);

   check_allocation_success(str1);
   strncpy(str1, "0123456789ABCDEF", 16);

   str2 = realloc(str1, 8);
   check_allocation_success(str2);

   printf("%s", str2);
   free(str2);
   return 0;
}

void check_allocation_success(char *ptr) {
   if (ptr == NULL) {
      printf("%s : %d : allocation failed.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

I know my question is duplicate but i am still confused. Some says we can't be sure the allocation always may free remaining block and some say we don't need to worry about old content.
If we dont need to worry about old content why is it still printing all old contents in above code.
I am using c99.

Comment: `realloc` shrinks the allocation, but if you need it to be zero terminated then you need to do that yourself. Shrinking the allocation doesn't mean it must move somewhere else in memory and accessing beyond the bounds of the new size is undefined behavior.

Comment: Remove how? Do you mean set the bytes to some value? Which value? Why spend CPU cycles doing that?

Comment: They are freed. You may no longer access them. That doesn't mean they will be changed in any way.